# MySQL desplegar resultados de id_cate ordenados por id_subcate

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Hola ¿cómo están? Les molesto con una pregunta?.

Me propuse agrupar productos según la subcategoría (id_subcate) pero al acceder a la Categoría (id_cate)

Parto de la base, como bien comenta y me hizo dar cuenta @amenadiel,

> Tu query únicamente usa el ID de la categoría principal

que tomo las url vía `$_GET` y que siempre estoy posicionado en la *Categoría* `productos.php?id_cate=7` allí accedo a un listado de todos los productos relacionados pero sin orden taxonómico.

Categorías

```
tbl_categorias id_cate id_catemaster nombre
```

Productos

```
tbl_productos id_prod id_cate id_subcate id_subnivcate nombre precio
```

Acá el id_subcate es un INT ej. *2*

Subcategorías

```
tbl_subcategorías id_subcate, id_cate, nombre
```

Acá el id_subcate es un VARCHAR ej. *prendas de torso*

Creo que debiera relacionar las tablas con JOIN y luego hacer Echo del nombre de la subcategoría en VARCHAR.-

**El siguiente es el esquema que espero lograr**

*Título de la Categoría (esto ya lo tengo)*

**Título de la subcategoría**

Productos que correspondan a la subcategoría

Luego un salto de línea `<br>`

**Título de otra subcategoría**

Productos que correspondan a la subcategoría

Luego un salto de línea `<br>`*

Aquí el código por donde voy que solo muestra los productos sin orden

```
<?php

$id_prod = $HttpVars->TraerGet('id_prod');
$id_subcate = $HttpVars->TraerGet('id_subcate');
$id_cate = $HttpVars->TraerGet('id_cate');
$id_subnivcate = $HttpVars->TraerGet('id_subnivcate');      

    if($id_cate != "") {
        //sql para titulo de categoria
        $sqltit = "SELECT nombre FROM tbl_categorias WHERE id_cate = ".intval($id_cate);
        //sql para los productos
        $sql = "SELECT P.id_prod, P.nombre, P.filech, P.precio, P.dcorta, P.publicado, P.id_cate, P.id_subcate ";
        $sql.= "FROM tbl_productos as P ";
        $sql.= "WHERE P.id_cate = ".intval($id_cate)." AND P.publicado = 1 and P.borrado = 0 ";
        $sql.= "ORDER BY P.id_subcate";
    } 

    $resulttit = $db->Query($sqltit,$connection);
    $myrowtit = mysqli_fetch_array($resulttit, MYSQLI_BOTH);

?>

<div class="titcate"><p><?php echo $myrowtit["nombre"]; ?></p></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<?php   
    $result = $db->Query($sql,$connection);
    $totreg = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($db->CantidadFilas($result) > 0){
        $cont=0;
        while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
            $precio = $myrow["precio"];
            $nombre = $myrow["nombre"];
            $cont++;
            $imagen = $myrow["filech"];
            $id_prod = $myrow["id_prod"];

            if($imagen == "") {
                $imagen = "noimagen.gif";}

?>

<div class="productoshome">
<p id="tit_prod"><? echo $nombre;?> </p>
<a title="<? echo $nombre ?>" href="<? echo "producto.php?id_prod=$id_prod/" ?>"></a>
<img src="timthumb.php?src=imgprod/<? echo $myrow['filech'] ?>&h=178&w=188&zc=1" alt="<? echo $nombre ?>" title="<? echo $nombre ?>" />
<p id="precio_prods">$ <? echo $precio ?></p>
</div>


<?php

        }

    } 


    else {
        echo "<p>No hay productos disponibles para esta categoría. <a href='index.php'>Haga click aquí para seguir navegando</a></p>";
    }
?>
```

Esto por ahora, hacen ya varios días que intento dar con la lógica adecuada..
gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu query únicamente usa el ID de la categoría principal, por lo cual el título que pones corresponde a alguna de las subcategorías hijas de la categoría `id_cat`. Luego listas los productos cuya categoría padre es `id_cat`. En ningún momento estás usando `id_subcate`. Tampoco veo un JOIN en donde intentes igualar por `id_subcate` como dice el enunciado de la pregunta.

Supongamos que:

1. en realidad quieres desplegar los resultados de una subcategoría.
2. (a falta de una tabla de categorías) tus categorías son

   - 1. prendas de vestir
   - 2. accesorios
3. tu tabla de subcategorías se ve asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y que tu tabla de productos se ve asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto, si quisieras listar `prendas torso` le pasarías la subcategoría 2. En ese caso, tu código debiera mostrar algo como:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el código mismo se vería así

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../conexion.php';

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$sql = 'SELECT cat.id_subcate,
            cat.nombre as subcategoria,
            prod.id_prod,
            prod.nombre,
            prod.precio
        FROM `tbl_subcategorias` cat
        JOIN tbl_productos prod ON cat.id_subcate = prod.id_subcate
        WHERE cat.id_subcate=?';

$cont       = 0;
$id_subcate = isset($_GET['id_subcate']) ? intval($_GET['id_subcate']) : 0;
if ($id_subcate !== 0 && $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {

    $stmt->bind_param('d', $id_subcate);

    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    while ($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $subcategoria = $myrow['subcategoria'];
        $id_prod      = $myrow['id_prod'];
        $precio       = $myrow['precio'];
        $nombre       = $myrow['nombre'];

        if ($cont === 0) {
            echo '<div class="titcate" style="font-size:1.5em"><p>' . $subcategoria . '</p></div>';
        }
        echo '<div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>';
        echo '<div class="productoshome" style="float:left;padding:3px;">';
        echo '<div id="tit_prod" style="float:left;width:100px;"><a title="' . $nombre . '" href="producto.php?id_prod=' . $id_prod . '" style="float:left;">' . $nombre . '</a></div>';

        echo '<div id="precio_prods" style="float:left;">$ ' . $precio . '</div>';
        echo '</div>';

        $cont++;
    }
    $stmt->close();

}
if ($cont == 0) {
    echo "<p>No hay productos disponibles para esta categoría. <a href='index.php'>Haga click aquí para seguir navegando</a></p>";
}
```

(Ejemplo: https://examples.ffflabs.com/listar_productos.php?id_subcate=2
  prueba con las subcategorías 1 (no hay resultados) 3, 4 y 5)
)

Si te fijas:

- mysql no se hace problemas haciendo un join entre un integer y un varchar dada tu estructura (donde id_subcate es un varchar pero con el formato de un integer)
- puse la variable usando una sentencia preparada, para que lo que recibas por GET no deje la puerta abierta a una inyección SQL.
- Además, compruebo que venga una subcategoría en el query string para que por debajo no se gatille un `NOTICE: undefined index id_subcate`.

---

## EDIT

Dado que ahora tenemos la tabla principal de categorías, me parece apropiado indicar que `id_subcate` en la tabla de subcategorías y la de productos debiera ser un número.

El valor "prendas torso" va en el campo "nombre" de la subcategoría.

Con esto la tabla de subcategorías es  prácticamente una tabla de paso entre categoría y producto. (conteniendo además el nombre de la subcategoría).

La tabla de productos no necesita un campo de subcategoría, por tercera forna normal siempre puede llegar a la tabla de categorías pasando por la de subcategoría.

Recapitulando, la tabla de **categorías** se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla de **subcategorías** (en donde convertí `id_subcat` en integer) se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la de **productos**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El esquema se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La query tendría que ser:

```
$sql = "SELECT cat.id_cate, 
           cat.nombre as nombre_categoria,
           subcat.id_subcate,
           subcat.nombre as nombre_subcategoria,
           prod.id_prod,
           prod.nombre,
           prod.precio
       FROM `tbl_categorias` cat
         JOIN tbl_subcategorias subcat USING (id_cate)
         JOIN tbl_productos prod USING (id_subcate)
       WHERE cat.id_cate= $id_cate
       ORDER BY cat.id_cate, subcat.id_subcate ";
```

(como ya sanitizaste `$id_cate` nos vamos a saltar la sentencia preparada)

El resultado se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el código sería: (tú lo acomodarás a tu html y sus estilos)

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../conexion.php';

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$id_cate = isset($_GET['id_cate']) ? intval($_GET['id_cate']) : 0;

$sql = "SELECT cat.id_cate,
           cat.nombre as nombre_categoria,
           subcat.id_subcate,
           subcat.nombre as nombre_subcategoria,
           prod.id_prod,
           prod.nombre,
           prod.precio
       FROM `tbl_categorias` cat
         JOIN tbl_subcategorias subcat USING (id_cate)
         JOIN tbl_productos prod USING (id_subcate)
       WHERE cat.id_cate= $id_cate
       ORDER BY cat.id_cate, subcat.id_subcate ";

$cont = 0;

if ($id_cate !== 0 && $result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    $nombre_categoria    = '';
    $nombre_subcategoria = '';
    while ($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // sólo se escribe el nombre de la categoría si cambió respecto de la anterior
        if ($nombre_categoria !== $myrow['nombre_categoria']) {
            $nombre_categoria = $myrow['nombre_categoria'];
            echo '<h2>' . $nombre_categoria . '</h2>';
        }

        // sólo se escribe el nombre de la subcategoría si cambió respecto de la anterior
        if ($nombre_subcategoria !== $myrow['nombre_subcategoria']) {
            $nombre_subcategoria = $myrow['nombre_subcategoria'];
            echo '<div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>';
            echo '<h3>' . $nombre_subcategoria . '</h3>';
            echo '<hr>';
        }
        $id_prod = $myrow['id_prod'];
        $precio  = $myrow['precio'];
        $nombre  = $myrow['nombre'];

        echo '<div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>';
        echo '<div class="productoshome" style="float:left;padding:3px;">';
        echo '<div id="tit_prod" style="float:left;width:100px;">';
        echo '<a title="' . $nombre . '" href="producto.php?id_prod=' . $id_prod . '" style="float:left;">' . $nombre . '</a></div>';
        echo '<div id="precio_prods" style="float:left;">$ ' . $precio . '</div>';
        echo '</div>';

        $cont++;
    }
}

if ($cont == 0) {
    echo "<p>No hay productos disponibles para esta categoría. <a href='index.php'>Haga click aquí para seguir navegando</a></p>";
}
```

Puedes probar 
https://examples.ffflabs.com/listar_productos2.php?id_cate=1

y
https://examples.ffflabs.com/listar_productos2.php?id_cate=2

Comment: Sí, gracias por tu respuesta. Corregí mi pregunta, estaba mal formulada. Si podés tomarte un rato para re-leerla y darle una nueva oportunidad te lo agradeceré, saludos.

Comment: 'get_result()' no funciona en mi phpini aún, bind_result() y fetch deberé usar. Podés darme pista de cómo incluir las claves del SELECT 'cat.id_subcate, cat.nombre as subcategoria' etc. dentro de bind_result()?

Comment: Voy a editar la respuesta, pero en general debieras mantener la pregunta original y editarla cuando quieras refinarla a partir de una respuesta. Esto es para que si alguien llega con tu misma duda inicial pueda seguir el hilo. Así como quedó no entenderá el problema original

Comment: Gracias @amenadiel, funciona y es lo que esperaba. Tenés razón, pero sabé que esto que pregunté es realmente lo que necesitaba, lo anterior estaba lejos aunque tenía más palabras clave en el título, las mismas se repiten en el cuerpo : /. che, gracias otra vez

Comment: Buen día @amenadiel, un solo inconveniente ha surgido y te lo comento. Mirá, uso varias dimensiones en el menú, ej. Cate > Subcate > Subnivcate pero hay algunos ítems que tienen sólo 2 niveles Cate > Subcate y en éstos, al hacer click en Subcate, el mensaje que recibo es No hay productos disponibles para esta categoría. Sin embargo cuando selecciono una Subcate que sí lleva Subnivcate, entonces sí muestra los productos. Utilizo un archivo php para cada opción, el de Subcate es el siguiente productos.php https://i.imgur.com/oKztBJZ.jpg

Comment: Ah, o sea de entrada usas lo que hablamos arriba pero en ciertos flujos lo mandas a otro archivo que hace una query distinta ¿Es eso? En ese caso usa `LEFT JOIN tbl_subnivelcate subcat USING (id_subcate)` en vez del JOIN solo. Y mejor poner esa cláusula después del join con la tabla de productos

Comment: Exacto, antes era mismo archivo para todo pero a tu respuesta decidí dividir archivos (uno en caso de id_cate, otro id_subcate, otro id_subnivcate). Pero hay un archivo para `id_subcate` que comparten 2 tipos de flujo (con o sin `id_subnivcate`). Tu recomendación no ha surtido efecto este es el cód. https://i.imgur.com/0Plnlr8.jpg

Comment: Hmmm pero estás seguro que quieres hacer el join con tbl_productos usando subnivcate? Porque si no tiene ese atributo entonces no llegas a la tabla producto y el resultado siempre es nulo. Quizás producto debiera joinearse usando id_subcate como antes

Comment: Sí, volví a joinear id_subcate quedó funcionando así `$sql = "SELECT cat.id_subcate,
           cat.nombre as nombre_categoria,
           subcat.id_subnivcate,
           subcat.nombre as nombre_subcategoria,
           prod.id_prod,
           prod.nombre,
           prod.filech,
           prod.precio
       FROM tbl_subcategorias cat
        JOIN tbl_productos prod USING (id_subcate)
        LEFT JOIN tbl_subnivelcate subcat USING (id_subnivcate)
       WHERE cat.id_subcate= $id_subcate
       ORDER BY cat.id_subcate,subcat.id_subnivcate";` muchas gracias!!, recomendá lecturas!